# How do I recursively find files with specific names and join using ImageMagick in Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, imagemagick

I have created an ImageMagick command to join images with certain names:

```
convert -append *A_SLIDER.jpg *B_SLIDER.jpg out.jpg
```

I have lots of folders with files named *A_SLIDER.jpg and *B_SLIDER.jpg next to each other (only ever one pair in a directory).

I would like to recursively search a directory with many folders and execute the command to join the images.

If it is possible to name the output image based on the input images that would be great e.g.

- **=>** `DOGS_A_SLIDER.jpg` and `DOGS_B_SLIDER.jpg` would combine to `DOGS_SLIDER.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, but back up first and try on a sample directory only!

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*A_SLIDER*" -execdir bash -c ' \
    out=$(ls *A_SLIDER*);
    out=${out/_A/}; \
    convert -append "*A_SLIDER*" "*B_SLIDER*" $out' \;
```

Find all files containing the letters "A_SLIDER" and go to the containing directory and start `bash` there. While you are there, get the name of the file, and remove the `_A` part to form the output filename. Then execute ImageMagick `convert` with the `_A_` and the corresponding `_B_` files to form the output file.

Or, a slightly more concise suggestion from @gniourf_gniourf... thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*A_SLIDER.jpg" -type f -execdir bash -c 'convert -append "$1" "${1/_A_/_B_}" "${1/_A/}"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! And thanks for the explanation as well

Comment: I don't really understand what your logic is in the statement `out=$(ls *A_SLIDER*)`. This looks dangerous and wrong to me (parsing `ls` is always—or nearly always—a very bad idea).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I am open to suggestions for improvement if you have some :-)

Comment: How about: `find . -name "*A_SLIDER.jpg" -type f -execdir bash -c 'convert -append "$1" "${1/_A_/_B_}" "${1/_A/}"' _ {} \;`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, thank you. That is more concise and I have edited it into my answer. I'll leave my original asnwer as I, personally, find these steps smaller and easier to understand/maintain/edit. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The "find" command will recursively search folders:

```
$ find . -name "*.jpg" -print
```

That will display all the filenames.  You might instead want "-iname" which does case-insensitive filename matching.

You can add a command line with "-exec", in which "{}" is replaced by the name of the file.  You must terminate the command line with "\;":

```
$ find . -name "*.jpg" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

You can use sed to edit the name of a file:

```
$ echo DOGS_A_SLIDER.jpg | sed 's=_.*$=='
DOGS
```

Can you count on all of your "B" files being named the same as the corresponding "A" files?  That is, you will *not* have "DOGS_A_SLIDER.jpg" and "CATS_A_SLIDER.jpg" in the same directory.  If so, something like the following isn't everything you need, but will contribute to your solution:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec "(echo {} | sed 's=_.*==')" \;
```

That particular sed script will do the wrong thing if you have any directory names with underscores in them.

"find . -type f" finds regular files; it runs modestly faster than without the -type.  Use "-d" to find directories.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I'm not quite sure how to get the imagemagick command into this too. I found an answer that did the trick tho cheers!

Comment: The part `-exec "(echo {} | sed 's=_.*==')" \;` is completely wrong. The system is going to try to execute a file named `(echo DOGS_A_SLIDER.jpg | sed 's=_.*==')` which, very likely, doesn't exist.